# React navigation v5 - how to open drawer from bottom tab and show drawer backside of bottom tab

Tags: react-native, react-navigation, react-navigation-bottom-tab

[image]Is there any way to open drawer from bottom tab and show back side of bottom tab.?
Anyone know about this?
[[image: 1]

[image]

Comment: What do you mean by 'show back side of bottom tab' ? 
if the drawer is the parent you can open it from the tab

Comment: @GuruparanGiritharan can you plz check above image. (Bottom tab with drawer). how can i do this?

Comment: ok i dont think thats possible, you are trying to have a drawer as the tab, one possible option i see is to use the useFocusEffect and open and close the drawer still not sure whether it will work

Comment: didnt work with useFocusEffect

Comment: Do you want the drawer inside the tab or outside the tab ?

Comment: need drawer inside the tab